# Yamaha DTX500 snare drum volume is much lower than the other drums

Tags: drums, electronic-music, snare-drum

I know that there is a dial under the snare drum to control its gain, but even when I turn it all the way up, the snare drum sound is still barely half that of all the other pads and cymbals.

Is there some way in the brain to calibrate that pad's volume?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the volume of this pad only from the controller? [Page 13](https://ca.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/6/323586/dtx500_en_om_b0.pdf)